# How does Python get only the Y component of an image?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I know that in MATLAB the image gets only y components.

How do I do this in Python?

I wrote the following code, but I do not know the details of Python.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image

for k in range(225):

    im = Image.open("C:/test/%d.png" % (k+1))
    im = Image.rgb2ycbcr(im);
    im = im(:, :, 1);
    im.save('C:/test2/%d.png' % (k+1))
```

I want to have only the Y component

In Python, there must be a function that converts rgb to ycbcr

What is that function?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `convert()` function available in PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('place the image path here')
ycbcr = image.convert('YCbCr')

y, cb, cr = ycbcr.split()
y.show()
```

Each of the individual channels (`y`, `cb` and `cr`) can be viewed using `show()`.

Comment: Thanks you very very much! Do you know how to save only y images?

Comment: @ONION Yes you can use the `save()` module like: `y.save(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\l_channel.png')`